# Add a library from Github to Android Studio 0.2.8

Tags: android, github, greendao, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a library [greenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO?source=cc) from Github to an Android project created in Android Studio. The content of latest build.gradle created are as follow

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

How to go about doing it?

Any pointer to latest blog on Gradle build system with added help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GreenDao is on Maven Central ([here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-690310554)) so you can reference it in your final `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.2'
}
```

Then just reference like you normally would. Android Studio will automatically download the jar file and build it into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'` to *build.gradle* and sync it. You can always check the latest version [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.greenrobot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22greendao-generator%22).

See this [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-how-to-integrate-greendao/) for a step by step greenDAO integration tutorial.